# Matching multiple lists within pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains information about types of products and shops in which they are available.

When a customer makes a purchase, he chooses products and adds them to the basket. The availability of the product and the shops in which they are stored looks like this:

| store_number | product_list | condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [[2,3],[2]] | 12345,123467 | 1 |
| [[2,3],[2],[4]] | 17875,15836,196357 | 1 |

The order can be fulfilled only if all products are in one same store or in two stores maximum. So it will be not too costly to deliver them from other stores.

I need to pick baskets that match this condition:  all of the products can be found in the same store, or part of the products are in one store and the second part - in another store. But the number of stores from which we can pick up the basket must be not higher than 2.

In the data frame above the first row matches the condition, because all of the products can be found in the store 2. The second row also matches the condition, because all of the products can be found in two stores - 2 and 4.

I have a function that checks up the similarity within all of the lists, but I have no idea of how to add the condition for two different stores.

```
def same_store(row):
    if len(set.intersection(*map(set, row['Store']))) > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    
df['flag'] = df.apply(same_store, axis=1)
```

Comment: I would start by creating a new df which has a column that is store no, and a column which has product lists for that store, using this df you can map the products in order against stores to determine if order can be filled by 1 or 2 stores.

Answer (score 0):

As @itprorh66 commented, I suggest you transform your data first.
The data you described is nested and unclear. I mean specifically, change your data like the example below (I've created only first row of your data).

```
data_dict = {'store_number': [2, 2, 3], 'product_list':[12345, 123467, 12345], 'condition': [1, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
```

If you transform your data like this, so called `long form data`, you can parse data more easily.

Furthermore, if you insist on that data structure, you might face data distortion when you save and load pandas DataFrame as `csv` or `xlsx`. Since saving list-like data in pandas Dataframe element literally increase dimension of data from 2 to 3.
And that might cause misinterpretation on other formats.